# how to remove the timestamp value from a file present in a list in python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have to remove timestamp value from files say

> (abc_20200124T141028.csv, bcd_20200124T141052) i.e.,this value(20200124T141028) present in a list a[]

How will I do?

Comment: Sorry, but it is difficult to understand your question. Are you wanting to remove the timestamp from the _filename_, or from the _contents_ of the file?

Comment: I want to remove the timestamp from the filename and what if there are multiple filenames present in a file and now we have to remove the timestamp from all those filenames, what we can do?

Comment: Why did you tag this question with Amazon S3 and AWS Lambda? Are these "files" stored in S3, or are they in the local filesystem?

Comment: What do you mean by "This value to compare that file with another file"?

Comment: my main problem is I have to remove the timestamp from filename which is present in a list, how can I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can split the name on the underscore using rsplit() and go to lower() to compare

ex:

```
name = 'HER_ADDRESS_data_20200124T141028.csv'
filename_noext, ext = name.rsplit("_",1)
# perform your test and do something
filename_noext.lower() + '.csv' == 'her_address_data.csv' # True
```

edited based on the clarification that it is a list of names. Just do it one by one?

```
namelist = ['HER_ADDRESS_data_20200124T141028.csv', 'NOT_HER_ADDRESS_data_20200124T141028.csv']

for name in namelist:
  filename_noext, ext = name.rsplit("_",1)
  # perform your test and do something
  filename_noext.lower() + '.csv' == 'her_address_data.csv' # True
```

Comment: thanks but if I use list instead of a particular name, then what I can write?